Configuring new users' "how to answer" help text
The description of the dynamic help text for new answerers says that it can be customized for a site. Is that something we can do as moderators? On the Chinese Language & Usage site we would like to add some notes on including at least a brief English translation of each answer.

It's not something you can do directly, but I'll be happy to help - just let me know what text you'd like.
For reference the current text reads:
Thanks for contributing an answer to Chinese Language and Usage - Stack Exchange!Please be sure to answer the question. Provide details and share your research!But avoid …Asking for help, clarification, or responding to other answers.Making statements based on opinion; back them up with references or personal experience.To learn more, see our tips on writing great answers.
